# JS library for image dragging, scrolling and zooming + markers on pictures like google maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, overlay, image

I'm looking for a google maps like js library just for a image. The features i need are simple: Drag, Scroll, Zoom and most important are markers (eventually vectors). But instead of a map I want to have one picture in the background.

Description of what the library should do: Think as it would be a map-similar situation. In this web app I want to have a image (e.g. a treasure map, map of a building) like the tiles in google maps. The image should be moveable and zoomable. Overlayed over the pictures should be markers. Markers can be as simple as letters (a,b,c), symbols, pointers, div elements... The markers are fixed to the image, positioned relative to its size (zoom) and position like on google maps. drag n drop support is needed for user interaction. While editing the resource a user may drop a new marker onto the map or move/delete an existing one. If the user is not in the editing mode the markers may funktion as tooltips or links. Also if clicking an link outside the "image", the image should scroll to the right position, to show the searched result on the "image"-map. The App should also work on mobile devices.

Has anyone already seen such a tool or is interessted in helping to develop it?

Regards Manuel

Comment: It should be usable within a mobile framework like phonegap! As already mentioned it should not be using a gps (long/lat) map in background since I only will have pictures/vectors.

Comment: I do realize this question is 7 years old but... have you found anything useful? A good suggestion would be really helpful for me.. otherwise I'll probably just try to implement it via google maps api... https://jsfiddle.net/a7vm63bw/1/

Comment: @xatenev. Haven't found anything nor needed since then

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 2):

How about [openlayers](http://openlayers.org/)?

It has a similar interface to google maps but allows you to customize the tiles/map and markers and doesn't rely on google's servers.

Comment: Thx for the fast answer, It others a lot but probably not what I need. i like it thou. But i need it only for one svg/img. Lake face tagging on face book. I want to tag special spots on the image + zoom. Nor is any example of interaction with the markers given for openlayers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom layers with Google Maps - so you could replace the entire map with your own tiles (image). Simple example is here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple.html or something more complicated http://mapwow.com/

Comment: not any close to what I need. I cannot use google groundoverlays since google maps ist still in the background.